# Executable path as a variable parameter to exec

Tags: c, linux, shell, parameter-passing, exec

I've an application which needs to call a specific program `'mips64-unknown-linux-gcc'` for linking all objects from a script with all required args for linking.
I am writing an `exec` function to call the compiler passed by script along with it's args. For this I wrote the code:

```
//prog.c : gcc prog.c -o prog
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   execvp("mips64-unknown-linux-gcc",argv);
}
```

This works, but the `mips64-unknown-linux-gcc` and `argv` are variables from script input.
I need `execv` first argument to be a variable which is compiler to be invoked. I can somehow (maybe) retrieve it by `getenv(”CC”)` but due to other dependencies my requirement is that exec shall accept the compiler and args at runtime (something like below). Is there any way I can do this?

```
./prog mips64-unknown-linux-gcc --sysroot=<<...>> -O3 -Wl -L <<...>> -L <<...>> -I <<...>> -L <<...>> abcd.o a1.o b2.o -o prog
```

I described my problem at my best. Please ask if anything is not clear.

Comment: First argument to `execv` is a pointer to a string. You can pass a local buffer instead of the sting literal if you want to get the program name from somewhere else. What exactly is your problem there?

Comment: Your parameter list in `main()` is not standard compliant.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv)` -> `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry, I used `execvp("gcc",argv);`. I want to pass the executable as a argument during program execution.

Comment: @SundeepKOKKONDA Then do it. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I understand this. As I mentioned, that is rather straight forward. What exactly is the problem when you try to do this? Is your question to get user intput? Is the question to take a command line option? What *specifically* is stopping you? And what did you try so far to get the string you want? Please edit your question to show your attempt to get the input you want. Then we can see how to get that string into `execv`.

Comment: @Gerhardh execvp(argv) : This gives error as too few params. (Here I thought of giving argv[0] as `gcc`)
execvp(cmd, argv): `cmd` I get it by `getenv()` but again this is same as `execvp("gcc", argv)`
A few other like this I tried but not worked.

Comment: `execvp` shall execute the program given during the runtime along with args what are passed. For eg: If `mips64-unknown-linux-gnu` is my program and `-Wl -O2 -L <....> -I <...> -o <...>` are my args.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe precisly how you want to call your program, what input you want to take, which of the command line options or which input you want to take as command and what shall happen to the other command line options. And also show what you have tried to achieve this. "A few other" is not useful. Also solutions that immediately can be determined to be wrong (like passing less arguments than mandatory) can be skipped for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Gerhardh I edited to my best. Let me know if anything needed.

Comment: Despite multiple requests, you still did not include what you tried. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again.

Answer (score 2):

From your example command line it seems that you want to take the first argument from command line as your command to execute and everything else should be passed to that command.

That is basically the same command line execpt for the first argument.
This makes things rather easy.

Looking at `argv` you will find these string:

```c
char *argv[] = {"proc","mips64-unkown-linux-gcc", "--sysroot=<<...>>", ..., "-o", "prog", NULL};`
```

You can use that and call your command:

```c
execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
```

Of course you should check whether you have at least one argument.

If you want do filter some options and handle in your own program instead of blindly passing it to `execvp` you must rebuild your own array of arguments where you do not include those options.